# SVN repository not found

Tags: eclipse, svn, unix

using my svn client ,
 i get the error

> svn: No repository found in

i tried to connect to svn server using telnet and it worked , but why can't i find the repository ?
is there a way to check if my repository is corrupted , any useful commands will be apreciated .

thanks

Comment: What command are you using exactly? What telnet command did you try?

Comment: Try to adjust protocols and ports for your connection. For example when svn is running on apache2 module you can use standard http and 80 port to connect.

Comment: i tried a simple Telnet Host 3690

Comment: i'm using eclipse SVN plugin as a client .

Comment: Have you tried with the command line client? Do a "svn ls <REPOURL>" to see if the server is responding.